# Здравствуйте,мне нужно вывести данные из нескольких таблиц в основную пустую

Tags: c#, sql

мне нужно вывести данные из нескольких таблиц в основную пустую,пытался сделать через where но все попытки тщетны,предполагаю что можно сделать  через оператор insert into и через join,можете подсказать как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас есть две схемы вывода данных.

1. Вы отдаёте SQL серверу команду "возьми данные отсюда и вставь их сюда". И он всё делает.

Это именно то, что Вы пытались сделать при помощи комдинации `insert into ... select` . Операция довольно простая, но нужно точное соответствие списка полей, котрые в INSERT и тех, которые в SELECT - частях этого выражения. И еще с identity - полями надо будет немного повозиться.

Преимущества: долго писать, быстро работает. Но метод не очень гибкий: какие то сложные преобразования данных так не сделать.

2. Вы все данные пропускаете через свою C# - программу. То есть, каждая строчка из SELeCT - части приходит в программу, в некотрый набор переменных. Потом из этого набора вы создаёте INSERT - выражение, и заполняете его данными.

Писть не сложно, но рабтает ораздо медленнее, так как все данные проходят через программу. Гибкость - необыкновенная, с данными в программе можно сделать вообще что угодно

я мог бы привести придуманный пример, но, мне кажется, и ак всё понятно. Вы можете задать вопрос в комментариях, или дать свой пример данных, котрые Вы хотите переносить.

Comment: *Операция довольно простая, но нужно точное соответствие списка полей* Некоторые диалекты поддерживают CREATE TABLE ... SELECT, у которого этой проблемы нет. Просто потом надо подрихтовать структуру до нужной без потери данных.

Comment: @Akina - спасибо, вот это новая для меня информация!

Comment: Например, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html